# Microsoft's Graph API calendar returns no value

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I was trying out Microsoft's API; I tried to invoke the Calendar API query given on 
[Permission-Documentation Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference)

```
/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-04-23T00:00:00&endDateTime=2017-04-29T00:00:00
```

I have set the scope to Calendars.Read.
However, even on providing valid dates, the value is blank in the Response JSON.
Can anyone let me know why this is happening?.
Thanks.
Edit : The response : 
`{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('myemailid%40outlook.com')/calendarView","value":[]}`

Comment: This is working properly for me. Could you post the JSON result you get from Graph Explorer?

Comment: Hi Marc following is the json response {\"@odata.context\":\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(\'myemailid%40outlook.com\')/calendarView\",\"value\":[]}\'

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT any idea what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your url seems to be the problem.

Try this instead:

```
GET /me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

Comment: Hi Erskan, still i get the same response